# PHP process can't terminate after end of script

Tags: php

I run PHP script in command line from CRON job. Once it complete a process, sometime PHP process still run on task manager as well as command prompt is active in windows forever, unless i kill manaully process from task manager. I put log file, it shows a code is working properly and end of the script. However, it does not exit from process and consume memory of server. I wonder is this bug of php ?

I run application in windows server 2003 and php is in CLI.

Comment: how do you determine that a particular php script has not terminated?

Comment: From process id and active command prompt which run in windows.